# Enviar un input type file vacio

Tags: php, html, mysql, archivo, input

Tengo un problema. He hecho un formualrio para enviar datos a una base de datos. Hasta ahi bien, pero se me ocurrió introducirle un input type file para permitir enviar imagen. Cuando envía algo con el input type relleno no hay problema. Pero si envías el inptut type file vacio da el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\publicar.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\publicar.php(25): file_get_contents('') #1 {main} thrown in
```

Lo que yo quiero es puedas mandar imagenes y texto, mandar solo imagenes o mandar solo texto, pero no puedo mandar solo texto. He probado poniendo al input type file un value con la dirección de una imagen en blanco (value="Imagenes/vacio.png") pero sigue dando el mismo error. Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.
El código del formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form action="publicar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" id ="input" required placeholder="¡Crappea la estupidez del día!" name="publicacion">
  <input type="text" id ="input2" value = "<?= $grupo2; ?>" name="grupo">
  <input type="file" name="imagen" style="opacity: 1"/><img id="cargarimagen" src="Imagenes/cargarimagen.png">
  <div id="avion2">
    <button type="submit" name="publicar">
      <img id="avion" src="Imagenes/avion.png">
    </button> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

Y el codigo que envía los datos es el siguiente:

```
if (isset($_POST['publicar'])){
    $publicacion = $_POST['publicacion'];
    $nombre= $user['nombre'];
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $query = "INSERT INTO publicaciones(nombre, publicacion, grupo, imagen) VALUES ('$nombre', '$publicacion', '$grupo', '$imagen')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$resultado){
    die("No estoy seguro, pero creo que el error está en que usted ha insertado código. Trate de volver a publicar sin el códiog. Gracias.");
    }
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Task Saved';
    $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
    header("location: Pagina.php?grupo2=".$grupo);
}
```

Comment: Hola, El mensaje es que no esta llegando una imagen. podrías probar colocándole un if -> $_FILES['imagen'] que si $imagen en caso de no subir ninguna, suba Imagenes/vacio.png

Comment: Podrías hacer una comprobación para verificar si la imagen existe, para ello podemos usar ```file_exist()```, ejemplo: ```if(file_exists($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])){ // imagen existe, sigues con tu codigo }```

Comment: Claro, tienes que comprobar si se ha subido un archivo, antes de usarlo para file_get_contents().

Comment: @AleBuo Muchas gracias. Funcionó perfecto.

Comment: @José Carlos PHP Muchas gracias. Funcionó perfecto.

Comment: @DBE Muchas gracias. Funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que comprobar si la el input esta vacío:

```html
if (isset($_POST['publicar'])){
    //validamos el campo imagen
    if($_FILES['imagen']['name'] != ""){
      $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
    else{
      $imagen  = "";
    }

    $publicacion = $_POST['publicacion'];
    $nombre= $user['nombre'];
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO publicaciones(nombre, publicacion, grupo, imagen) VALUES ('$nombre', '$publicacion', '$grupo', '$imagen')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$resultado){
    die("No estoy seguro, pero creo que el error está en que usted ha insertado código. Trate de volver a publicar sin el códiog. Gracias.");
    }
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Task Saved';
    $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
    header("location: Pagina.php?grupo2=".$grupo);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funcionó perfecto.